# Openvpn Bridge - can connect but no LAN or WAN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, bridge

I have had a routed openvpn server running for some time.

I am trying to set up a bridged connection so that my vpn will be on the same subnet.

I have the following config file for the server. When I try and connect, I can, it will successfully do it. But I have no internet connection, local vpn connection. I also cannot ping the VPN sever.

Please could I have a hand?! What else do you need to see?

VPN IP: 10.0.1.4
Subnet: 255.255.254.0
Gateway: 10.0.0.1

```
dev tap0
tls-server
proto tcp
port 443
port-share 127.0.0.1 444
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh4096.pem
topology subnet
user nobody
group nogroup
server-bridge 10.0.1.4 255.255.254.0 10.0.1.60 10.0.1.70
mssfix
persist-key
persist-tun
#log /var/log/openvpn
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
verb 4
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
mute 50
#set the dns servers
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.0.1.2"
#For windows, to make the network recognized
push "route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.1.4"
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
log-append /var/log/openvpn
comp-lzo
```

Answer (score 0):

Revert your config to the last working one (without bridging), then you install the package bridge-utils and run the following commands (in the example i'm bridging your tap0 - eth0):

```
# switch to superuser and create the bridging interface
sudo bash
brctl addbr br0

# kill the bridged interfaces and add them to the bridge
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 down
ifconfig tap0 0.0.0.0 down
brctl addif br0 eth0
brctl addif br0 tap0

# unshut the interfaces
ifconfig eth0 up
ifconfig tap0 up
ifconfig br0 up

# add ip addresses and rib information
ifconfig br0 10.0.1.4 netmask 255.255.254.0
route add default gw 10.0.0.1 br0
```

You may want to add another local IP address as well. If so, add it to the bridge interface (br0). Good luck!